# stop Propagation in jquery

Tags: jquery

If i'm using  stop Propagation to stop page from closing and use button
(`closeDropdown`)to close the page and both are same page how to code in
jQuery i'm using this but page is stopping, but button is not working.

```
  $('.mydropdown').click(function (e) {
        $('body').click(function (g) {
            g.stopPropagation();
        })
    }).on('show.bs.dropdown', function (event) {
        var ct = event.currentTarget;
        $('.closeDropdown').click(function (e) {
            $(ct).removeClass("open");
        })
    })
```

Comment: You should not declare one click handler inside another unless you really do not need it. So your body.click handler should be declared inside document ready handler, but not inside .mydropdown click. And what do you want to receive? What do you expect?

Comment: What does this had to do with `jquery-ui`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .on('show.bs.dropdown', function (event) {
>               var ct = event.currentTarget;
>               $('.closeDropdown').click(function (e) {
>                   $(ct).removeClass("open");
>               })  $('.filter').click(function (e) {
>                                    e.stopPropagation();
>                                });
>
> and add drop down class or id .filter or #.filter.
>   it's work